# How to use cursor with update statment?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, cursor

My aim is to `update` some records with range of numbers (4987-4993) the first record should be with the number 4987 the next 4988..etc' and when the loop condition is @a=4993 it should stop, I tried using SQL cursor but I updated every thing with the same number (4992).... what am I missing?

```
DECLARE @a AS INT;
DECLARE @b AS INT;

select @a = 4987

declare myCursor cursor for 
select  modelcode from model
where try_cast(modelcode as int) > 1600 and try_cast(modelcode as int) <1700

open myCursor

fetch next from  myCursor into @b

while @a < 4993
   begin
     update model
     set ModelCode = @a 
     where try_cast(modelcode as int) < 1659

     select @a = @a+1
     fetch next from myCursor into @b
     end;
close myCursor

DEALLOCATE myCursor;
```

Comment: You could do this without cursors, in a single update statement?

Comment: Your cursor doesn't even have a `from` clause.  I would suggest that you delete this question and ask a new question about how to do what you want without a cursor.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why are you trying to cast the value of a column in the `WHERE` to an `int`? Are you storing numerical data in a `varchar`?

Comment: @CaiusJard how can I do it in a single update with a specifi range?

Answer (score 0):

Your `update` statement is independent from `@b`. You need to do something like this:

```
 update model
 set ModelCode = @a 
 where modelcode = @b;
```